# Stockfish shows only 2 next moves

Tags: engines, stockfish

For Position `1r2k1r1/pq1b1p2/1p1Rp1p1/2p1P3/2B2P2/P1N1K1P1/1P2Q3/8 b - -`

stockfish analysis ouput is like

```
info depth 12 seldepth 17 multipv 1 score cp 258 nodes 80180 nps 76874 hashfull 14 tbhits 0 time 1043 pv b6b5 c3e4 b5c4 e4f6 e8f8 f6d7 f8g7 d7b8 g8b8 d6d2 b7b3 e3e4 c4c3 b2c3 b3a3 d2d3

info depth 13 seldepth 22 multipv 1 score cp 130 nodes 122237 nps 81437 hashfull 25 tbhits 0 time 1501 pv b6b5 c4d3
```

As you can see stockfish only show 2 moves sequences for depth 13 `b6b5 c4d3`,

Can I somehow force stockfish to show at least 5 moves sequences?

Comment: The only way to get a longer line from Stockfish is to wait. Basically if Stockfish shows such a short line it does not know itself how the line continues. But if you wait, eventually it will hopefully figure it out.

Comment: @koedem Thanks for commenting:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. That's how Stockfish internally works. You are going to need to check your previous line with the current line. If the current line has fewer moves, discard it.

Comment: Thanks, it was helpful : )

Answer (score 2):

There's no setting to get Stockfish to display the next X moves. This is for technical reasons: when a search [fails high](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Fail-High) or fails low (see also [aspiration window](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Aspiration_Windows)), Stockfish doesn't know what the next X moves are going to be either, it just knows what the current best move it has found is.

That said if you wait longer, Stockfish will eventually display a longer principal variation.

Comment: Thanks for your help:)

Comment: "There's no setting to get Stockfish to display the next X moves....it just knows what the current best move it has found is." How do I get it only to show the one best move it has found?

Comment: @lmat-ReinstateMonica Set the number of principal variations to 1.